# (in excel) randomly generating a power law distribution

Tags: excel, random, distribution, power-law

I am trying to simulate a number of different distribution types for a project using Excel. Right now, I have generated a normal distribution with a mean of 35 and a standard deviation of 3.33. So far so good.

I would like to also generate some other distribution types.

One I have tried is a lognormal. To get that, I am using the following code:

```
=(LOGNORM.INV(RAND(),LN(45^2/SQRT(45^2+3.33^2)),SQRT(LN((45^2+3.33^2)/4.5^2))
```

It produces some output, but I would welcome anyone's input on the syntax.

What I really want to try to do is a power law distribution. From what I can tell, Excel does not have a built-in function to randomly generate this data. Does anyone know of a way to do it, besides switching software packages?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

E

Comment: What do you mean by "power law distribution"? It doesn't seem to correspond to a well-defined distribution such as a beta distribution but instead seems to be a family of distributions. In other words -- there are different *kinds* of power law distributions. Which kind are you asking about?

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your reply. I would say a Pareto distribution (type 1) would probably be the best fit for what I am trying to generate. What I am basically trying to do is capture the effect of a long tail, so, in that sense, any member of the power law family would probably work. Although I would ideally want a probably distribution function and not a cumulative distribution function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the (type I) Pareto distribution, if the parameters are a min value `xm` and an exponent `alpha` then the cdf is given by

```
p = 1 - (xm/x)^alpha
```

This gives the probability, `p`, that the random variable takes on a value which is <= `x`. This is easy to invert, so you can use [inverse sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) to generate random variables which follow that distribution:

```
x = xm/(1-p)^(1/alpha) = xm*(1-p)^(-1/alpha)
```

If `p` is uniform over [0,1] then so is `1-p`, so in the above you can just use `RAND()` to simulate 1/p. Thus, in Excel if you wanted to e.g. simulate a type-1 Pareto distribution with `xm = 2` and `alpha = 3`, you would use the formula:

```
= 2 * RAND()^(-1/3)
```

If you are going to be doing this sort of thing a lot with different distributions, you might want to consider using R, which can be called directly from Excel using the [REXcel add-in](http://www.statconn.com/products.html). R has a very large number of built-in distributions that it can directly sample from (and it also uses a better underlying random number generator than Excel does).

Comment: John, Thanks ever so much for your comment. This is extraordinarily helpful. I have never tried R (been meaning to learn for a while now). Thanks again. I really appreciate your taking the time. I will try this out today.

Comment: Glad to help. If the answer works for you, you could always make it as "accepted".

Comment: I have been playing around with the construction of type 1 power laws that you recommended. They form the correct shape and all seems well. I noticed, however, that with the structure of the equation for the simulated data means that a smaller exponent (alpha) results in a larger or more pronounced distribution. Mathematically, I understand why, since -1/0.5 is larger, for example, than -1/3, but it is a bit counter intuitive to think that a smaller alpha results in a more pronounced distribution. Do you happen to know of a good resource to explain why this is the case? Thanks!

Comment: I don't really have a lot of familiarity with the distribution so I lack intuition about the meaning of the exponent. Perhaps this can shed light on it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_index (even though this is specifically about economic applications it might help with non-economic interpretations as well).

Comment: Thanks, John. I will take a look and see if I can't suss out the meaning here. When I do, I will let you know.